# Sql query to remove duplicates depending on two particular columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I am having a table called `BUS_DATA` that returns below rows when running below query

```
query select * from BUS_DATA
```

[image]

I then run below query to get info only for the bus with id `4-3323309834`

```
select * from BUS_DATA where busId = '4-3323309834'
```

Below are the rows that i get when i run the above query

[image]

What i would like to achieve is to only return the row with the maximum `currentSpeed` for that particular `dataDateTime` like below so that i don't get two have two records for a particular day.

[image]

I have tried below query but its still returning two records for each date

```
select busId, dataDateTime, max(currentSpeed) as CURRENTSPEED from `BUS_DATA` WHERE busId = '4-3323309834' group by busId, dataDateTime
```

I would also like the query to return other columns like `passengersNo` and `speedLimit` which the above query is not returning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use a partition to achieve this.  Group by the BusID and the Date, but your date is date time, so you would want to cast or convert to just a date so the 27th all group together, etc...    Then you could order by the Current speed by desc putting the fastest at the top.

```
SELECT
X.*
FROM
(
SELECT
BusID
, BusName
, CurrentSpeed
, PassengersNo
, SpeedLimit
, dataDateTime
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(dataDateTime AS DATE), BusId ORDER BY CurrentSpeed DESC) AS RowNumOrder
FROM BUS_DATA 
WHERE busId = '4-3323309834'
) AS X 
WHERE X.RowNumOrder = 1
```

Comment: where is BusinessId coming from

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo BUSID, I corrected it.

Comment: can i have a syntax like the one above for oracle db this one is only working with the normal mysql that comes with xamp

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo I added another answer to the post, it's the aliases most likely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work with Oracle.  The As doesn't work with alias on sub selects and joins in Oracle.

```
SELECT
X.*
FROM
(
SELECT
b.BusID
, b.BusName
, b.CurrentSpeed
, b.PassengersNo
, b.SpeedLimit
, b.dataDateTime
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(b.dataDateTime AS b.DATE), b.BusId ORDER BY b.CurrentSpeed DESC) RowNumOrder
FROM BUS_DATA b
WHERE b.busId = '4-3323309834'
) X 
WHERE X.RowNumOrder = 1
```

Comment: is it possible to have one single query without  Select inside another Select because IntelliJ DataGrip is asking me whether it should run the outer `Select X.* FROM` or the inner `SELECT
BusID, BusName.......`

Comment: I added aliases to the inner query can you try running that?