# Unable to resolve symbol 'X' when converting MySQL DDL to Oracle SQL DDL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am having below query which is working well until i take it to Oracle SQL

```
SELECT
    X.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            BusID,
            BusName,
            CurrentSpeed,
            PassengersNo,
            SpeedLimit,
            dataDateTime,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY CAST(dataDateTime AS DATE), BusId
                ORDER BY CurrentSpeed DESC
            ) AS RowNumOrder
    FROM
        BUS_DATA 
    WHERE
        busId = '4-3323309834'
    ) AS X 
WHERE
    X.RowNumOrder = 1
```

When i take to oracle sql i get the error

> Unable to resolve symbol 'X'.

Below is what i have tried but the query is just running without returning any results.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
BusID
, BusName
, CurrentSpeed
, PassengersNo
, SpeedLimit
, dataDateTime
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(dataDateTime AS DATE), BusId ORDER BY CurrentSpeed DESC) AS RowNumOrder
FROM BUS_DATA 
WHERE busId = '4-3323309834'
) WHERE RowNumOrder = 1
```

Below is what i tried according to `user5683823` answer but its just asking me to run the queries in two seperate ways

```
SELECT X.*
FROM
(
SELECT
BusID
, BusName
, CurrentSpeed
     ,PassengersNo
, SpeedLimit
, dataDateTime
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(dataDateTime AS DATE), BusId ORDER BY CurrentSpeed DESC) RowNumOrder
FROM BUS_DATA
WHERE busId = '4-3323309834'
) X
WHERE X.RowNumOrder = 1
```

Below is how i have edited the query according to how Rick James is suggesting but i am getting `Unable to resolve column 'RowNumOrder'` error

```
SELECT
BusID
, BusName
, CurrentSpeed
     ,PassengersNo
, SpeedLimit
, dataDateTime
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(dataDateTime AS DATE), BusId ORDER BY CurrentSpeed DESC) RowNumOrder
FROM BUS_DATA
WHERE busId = '4-3323309834' HAVING X.RowNumOrder = 1
```

The original question i asked was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73583134/sql-query-to-remove-duplicates-depending-on-two-particular-columns) but the solutions provided there were not working for oracle

Comment: Would it work to eliminate the _outer_ `SELECT` and change to `HAVING X.RowNumOrder = 1`?

Comment: What is the data type you are using for dataDateTime column in Oracle?

Comment: @Ahmed i am using timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in Oracle SQL, you can give an alias to a subquery (like you were doing in MySQL), but you are not allowed to use the keyword `AS` - you must remove that word between the subquery (the closing parenthesis) and the alias `X`. In Oracle SQL, the keyword `AS` is permitted (and optional!) only before column aliases, but not before aliases for table expressions (tables listed in `from` clause, subqueries, table function invocations, etc.)

Incidentally, you are using the term DDL incorrectly; no matter what the SQL dialect, a `select` statement is not DDL, it is a limited form of DML. The distinction is crucial: executing a `select` statement doesn't implicitly commit earlier DML statements.

For the second query, if you expect results but none are returned, are you sure the data exists in the `BUS_DATA` table? You can find out, for example, by running a simple query, like `select * from bus_data where rownum = 1`. If data is missing, perhaps it was inserted in a different **session** (perhaps even by you, but from a different connection), and has not been committed yet? Otherwise see if there is any data for that specific business id: add `and busid = ...` to my very simple query, earlier in this paragraph.

Comment: can i get an example of how the query will look like

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo - I think I explained that in my answer. Remove the word  **AS** from the query. You mat then get an empty result, as you are getting now with your second query. Why that is, I gave a few suggestions in my answer as well.

Comment: @user5683823 i have updated the question on  what i have tried but when i am running the query i am getting a dialog in Intellij Data Grip asking which statements do you want to run and its showing me the inner query in brackets option query and also the outside query select * from  query and if i run any of them its still not working its just returning all the records